# htaccess sitea.com/1 to siteb.com/1

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i want to create with htaccess that if you go to www.website1.com/page.php that you go to www.website2.com/page.php, and www.website1.com/foo/bar/index.php to www.website2.com/foo/bar/index.php redirects. How can i do that with htaccess? Example please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `mod_rewrite` is available, you can put this code into the `.htaccess` of `www.website1.com`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website1\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website2.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

This would redirect every page on `website1.com` to the equivalent on `website2.com`